# Searching by category dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a product filter by category to my application via a drop-down list, but the problem here is that i'm trying to use two models at the same time and i'm not sure how to fix it, nor how to apply the filter to the product, the modelization of the products and categories are as follows :

```
 public partial class Stz_Product
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Stz_Product()
        {
            this.Stz_Cart = new HashSet<Stz_Cart>();
        }
    
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsDelete { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsFeatured { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Stz_Category Stz_Category { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Stz_Cart> Stz_Cart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
public partial class Stz_Category
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Stz_Category()
        {
            this.Stz_Product = new HashSet<Stz_Product>();
        }
    
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsDelete { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Stz_Product> Stz_Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the controller for this view :

```
public ActionResult Category(string search, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CategoryList= GetCategory();
            HomeIndexViewModel model = new HomeIndexViewModel();
            return View(model.CreateModel(search, 4, page));
        }
public GenericUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new GenericUnitOfWork();
        public List<SelectListItem> GetCategory()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var cat = _unitOfWork.GetRepositoryInstance<Stz_Category>().GetAllRecords();
            foreach (var item in cat)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.CategoryId.ToString(), Text = item.CategoryName });
            }
            return list;
        }
```

and the HTML view code is as follows :

```
@model Ecommerce_Project.Models.Home.HomeIndexViewModel
@model Ecommerce_Project.DBase.Stz_Product;
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Category";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{
    List<SelectListItem> data = ViewBag.CategoryList;
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, data, "---Select---", new { @class = "form-control" })
<div class="row producut-container">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ListOfProducts)
    {
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-sx-6" style="margin-bottom:8px">
            <div class="thumbnail product-item" style="height:300px">
                <img class="img-responsive" title="Cliquer pour voir les details du produit"
                     style="cursor:pointer;height:160px;width:260px" src="~/Productimg/@item.ProductImage" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5> @item.ProductName </h5>
                    <p> @item.Price Dh</p>
                    <p>
                        @if (item.Quantity > 0)
                        {
                            using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Home", new { productId = item.ProductId }, FormMethod.Post))
                            {
                                <button type="submit" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                            }
                        <p>En Stock </p>
                    }
                    else
                    { <p>Pas de Stock </p>}
                        <div class="product-item-badge">
                            @if (item.IsFeatured == true)
                            {
                                <p>Nouveau</p>
                            }
                            else
                            { <p>Promotion</p>}
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        }
    <br />
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.ListOfProducts, page => Url.Action("Category", new { page, search = Request.QueryString["search"] }), new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<form></form>` to submit the value of dropdownList and Query by condition in the controller, then return the result.

I write a simple demo you can refer to：

***Model***

```
public class CustomerModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

***controller***

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /Home/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            BindDropDownList();

            return View(Customers());
        }


        private void BindDropDownList()
        {
           //For the convenience of demonstration, I just used hard coding
            List<SelectListItem> countries = new List<SelectListItem>();
            countries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
            countries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "USA" });
            countries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "UK" });
            countries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "China", Value = "China" });
            ViewBag.countries = countries;

            List<SelectListItem> cities = new List<SelectListItem>();
            cities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
            cities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "London", Value = "London" });
            cities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Shanghai", Value = "Shanghai" });
            cities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "La", Value = "La" });
            cities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Birmingham", Value = "Birmingham" });
            ViewBag.cities = cities;
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string country, string city)
        {
           //Accept the value of the drop-down list and make a conditional query

            List<CustomerModel> customers = Customers();
            if (country != "0")
            {
                customers = customers.Where(x => x.Country == country).ToList();
            }

            if (city != "0")
            {
                customers = customers.Where(x => x.City == city).ToList();
            }

            BindDropDownList();
            return View(customers);
        }

        private List<CustomerModel> Customers()
        {
            List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel>();
            customers.Add(new CustomerModel { Id = 1, Name = "Rohit", City = "Shanghai", Country = "China" });
            customers.Add(new CustomerModel { Id = 2, Name = "John", City = "London", Country = "UK" });
            customers.Add(new CustomerModel { Id = 3, Name = "Smith", City = "La", Country = "USA" });
            customers.Add(new CustomerModel { Id = 4, Name = "Lily", City = "London", Country = "UK" });
            customers.Add(new CustomerModel { Id = 5, Name = "Ching", City = "Birmingham", Country = "UK" });

            return customers;
        }
    }
```

***view***

```
@model List<DropdownListTest2.Models.CustomerModel>

    <div>   

         @* use `<form>` to submit the value of dropdownlist*@

        <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
            Country: <select asp-items="@ViewBag.countries" name="country"></select>
            City : <select asp-items="@ViewBag.cities" name="city"></select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
        <hr />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var customer in @Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@customer.Id</td>
                    <td>@customer.Name</td>
                    <td>@customer.City</td>
                    <td>@customer.Country</td>
                </tr>
            }                    
        </table>
    </div>
```

[image]